# Force type parameter to be invariant at use-site when it is covariant at declaration site

Tags: generics, reflection, kotlin, covariance, generic-variance

I am building an extension function on `KProperty1`. The function needs to accept an argument that extends the value type of property (`R`), even though `KProperty1` is covariant in the type parameter `R`.

A slightly contrived example would be the following, though my use is more legitimate.

```
data class Data(val value: String)

fun <V> KProperty1<*, V>.setMagically(value: V) {
    this.javaField?.set(null, value)
}

fun test() {
    // I would like this to fail to compile
    Data::value.setMagically(190)
}
```

It would seem that the compiler is inferring the type `Any` for `R`, which is totally valid, since `KProperty1<*, String> : KProperty1<*, Any>`

What I want is to say that for my particular case, I actually want `V` to be invariant. I know you can use `out` and `in` as variance wideners, but I was unable to figure out how to specify that I want to override the covariant annotation on `KProperty1` with invariance for this case.

It's worth noting that it works great with `KMutableProperty1`, since that's invariant in `R`. But my code needs to work with non-mutable properties as well.

For context, I'm building something that generates database queries, which is why I need the value to be a subclass of the property type, even though I'm not actually writing to the property, but this question is more general than my specific, property-handling case.

Comment: I cross-posted this on discuss.kotlinglang.org as well: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/generic-parameter-use-site-invariance-modifier/5344

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible in Kotlin. In fact, there is an internal annotation which enables this behavior (causes the compiler to report an error, if `Any` is inferred although nowhere at the call site was it mentioned) and it's used in several places in `kotlin-stdlib`, but using it outside of the standard library is still discouraged.

We have plans to make this annotation public. For more details, please check out [KT-13198](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13198).