# How to stop Kotlin from widening types?

Tags: kotlin, generics, reflection

So I'm trying to define a method like this

```kotlin
fun <R,F> myFunction(prop: KProperty1<R, F>, value:F)  {}


// so that the compiler only allows me to invoke it like 
myFunction(User::name, "Alejandro")
// and stops developers from doing illegal things like
myFunction(User::name, 123)

//However, compiler doesn't complain if I do that... it widens the type to Any
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39596420/4161471 https://stackoverflow.com/q/39812227/4161471

Comment: KMongo achieves it using an annotation on the type param, but I don't see what it does.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is a use case for this? I can think of things you might want to do with a KMutableProperty and item of matching return type, but not really for a read-only property. Anyway, the Checker class solution in the 2nd link above could be adapted for your situation here.

Comment: The annotation that KMongo uses is `@kotlin.internal.OnlyInputTypes`. There are more details in KT-13198, including [how to access it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13198/#focus=Comments-27-5102119.0-0). It doesn't look like it will be released into stdlib any time soon.

Comment: @Tenfour04 typesafe query builder

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin is "widening" the type here because the value type parameter (i.e. the second type parameter) of `KProperty1` is defined with keyword `out` which makes that parameter *covariant*.

This means that for instance `KProperty1<User, String>` is a subtype of `KProperty1<User, Any>`, and hence `User::name` which is presumably a `KProperty1<User, String>`, can also be seen as a special case of `KProperty<User, Any>`. Therefore, it is totally legal to call `myFunction<User,Any>(User::name, 123)`.

The logic behind this can be derived from the name of the `out` keyword: It is expected that the typed parameter is only used in "out position" of any function call. In the case of `KProperty1` this makes sense, because it is the type of the return value of the property. When you get a value from a `KProperty1<K, V>`, that value is of type `V` and thus it can be used anywhere where it is okay to have some supertype of `V`.

This should only be a problem, if you want to use the value in the "in position" of some function, for instance, if you want to write a function that takes a value of type `V` and store it in a `KProperty1<K, V>`.

If this is what you want, you are lucky, because you can and should just use `KMutableProperty1<K,V>` where the value parameter does not have an `out` keyword which means that it is *invariant*. Also, that interface allows you to put the value into the property.

Changing your function definition to

```kotlin
fun <R,F> myFunction(prop: KMutableProperty1<R, F>, value:F)  {}
```

makes that the compiler allows `myFunction(User::name, "Alejandro")`, but it complains on `myFunction(User::name, 123)`.

See also: [Kotlin documentation on Variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance)

Comment: I get that variance is the reason it happens. Somehow KMongo forces KProperty to be invariant at call site using some sort of magic (https://litote.org/kmongo/typed-queries/) (https://github.com/Litote/kmongo/blob/8e1496a0ff787e0c188677ef91dfa35f462293d6/kmongo-property/src/main/kotlin/org/litote/kmongo/Filters.kt#L40). It is also mentioned here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191898/force-type-parameter-to-be-invariant-at-use-site-when-it-is-covariant-at-declara) that is is possible somehow...